# Do Laravel and CodeIgniter have the same hash function?

Tags: laravel, codeigniter

I have this  situation. I have to create a login with rest api using laravel. This project is created using CodeIgniter.
Will it be the same hash password ?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel [uses Bcrypt and now also supports Argon2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/hashing) aswell.

From what I know, codeigniter [recommends using](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html) [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). It depends on the algorithm parameter passed back when hashing the passwords.